# No-maj and witch family punishments?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

I'm writing fanfic, and the mother who's a witch falls in love with a no-maj, and then they have children together. I want them to get captured, and I either want them to escape or get punished, but idk what their punishment would be, any ideas???

Comment: I don't think this kind of question is a good fit for this forum. Basically: you're the author, you just open up that tin called "imagination" and come up with whatever punishment you like! This is called "narrative necessity" and is, I believe,  outside the scope of SciFi & Fantasy.

Comment: This question would be better suited to the world building stack exchange, its not a bad question its just in the wrong section of this site. Could anyone with enough rep move it for him?

Answer (score 1):

## The magic user involved would go to jail.

Though Queenie wanted to marry Jacob, Jacob cautioned her against it because she, as the one with magical abilities in the relationship, would be thrown in jail.

> “**JACOB**
>
> Okay, wait. We talked about this, like, a million times. If we get married and they find out, they’re gonna throw you in jail, sweetheart. I can’t have that. They don’t like people like me marrying people like you. I ain’t a wizard. I’m just me.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

It is not specified what wizarding law enforcement would do with the No-Maj in the relationship, but presumably they would simply be Obliviated.